# Trying to use JBoss profiler but it fails to parse the jboss-profiler-noAOP.sar file

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, jboss, profiler, openjdk-17

**I followed the instructions to setup the profiler given here:**

http://www.mastertheboss.com/articles/application-server/jboss-profiler-tuning/

**When I start my server, I get this error:**

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jboss-profiler-noAOP.sar".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jboss-profiler-noAOP.sar"
service jboss.deployment.unit."Data_Structures_war_exploded.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Data_Structures_war_exploded.war"

My deployment directory

[Directory][1]

Answer (score 1):

You are not using JBoss 4 but WildFly thus following out of date instructions isn't going to work at all. The beginning of the article give you some pointers addressing different version of the server.

Comment: I never realized that WildFly can't be configured like JBoss. Thank you for pointing it out.